# What is JSP 2 version of <c:set>?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, el

How can I set a value using JSP 2?

I mean, if `${val}` is the new version of `<c:out value="${val}" />`, what is the JSP 2 version of `<c:set var="val" value="bla" />`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confused. `${val}` is *not* the new version of `<c:out value="${val}" />`. Both are Expression Language (EL) statements.*

In JSP 2, you still use `<c:set var="val" value="bla" />`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages#JSP_2.0

<sub>`*`okay, okay, so while `${val}` *is* an EL statement, `<c:out value="${val}" />` is a JSTL tag that *uses* an EL expression.</sub>

---

The JSP 2 section of the Wikipedia article has parts copied verbatim from [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/).

Comment: What does JSP 2 bring to the table then? Only a shortcut for the <c:out value="${val}" />? I know I can now write ${val} and it is evaluated on place instead of by the c:out tag. Is that the only change?

Comment: It's not necessarily a shortcut. JSP2 just started to support EL in template text. Prior to JSP2, EL was only evaluated in tag attribtues. The `<c:out>` does by the way one more thing: escaping XML entities. So, EL in template text does essentially the same as `<c:out value="${foo}" escapeXml="false" />`. Also note that JSTL should not be confused with EL.

Comment: Is the `<c:out>` XML escaping equivalent to `${fn:escapeXML(foo)}` JSTL function?